# How to click on checkbox span class using VBA Selenium

Tags: vba, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, bots

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxaJt.png)

htmlcode:

How can i check all checkbox in this tables (on pic)?
vba code and selenium.
thanks alot

```
bot.FindElementByClass("ui-chkbox-icon ui-icon ui-icon-blank ui-c").Click
```

its not work.

Comment: are you getting any error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this helps

```vb
driver.FindElementByXPath(".//span[@class='ui-chkbox-icon ui-icon ui-icon-blank ui-c']").Click
```

If not, try to click on the div. Assuming the div class is unique

```vb
driver.FindElementByXPath(".//div[@class='ui-chkbox-box ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-state-default']").Click
```

Comment: can you make a loop for all checkbox?

Comment: Can you share the url?

Comment: no i cant because its need user and pass.

Comment: but in the pic you can see it (attach pic)

Comment: can you try to click on the div. See my answer for an update

Comment: yes yes yes yes its work for first checkbox ,please only help me for loop for all check box

Comment: Can you accept the answer if i have answered your ask?

Comment: yes is will , can you place the code on the loop for all checkbox?

Comment: where is your checkboxes located> Is it inside each tr?

Comment: Yes it's In tr and td